# Checking if the sequence converges or not

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

While exploring the function $y = x^{x^{x^{.^.}}}$, I tweaked it a little bit to result in $y = x^{{1/x}^{x^{{1/x}^{x^{{1/x}^{.^.}}}}}}$. It can be easily shown that the second function can be maximized using the equation $y = x^{{1/x}^y}$. This can also be verified using the [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vpwfjyzymi). The maximum value occurs near $x = 2$ and is approximately $1.32$.

Now, if I form a sequence with the general term defined like below: 
$$a_n = 2^{1/2^{3^{{1/3}^{.^{.^{n^{1/n}}}}}}}$$, then how can I show if it converges or not (along with finding the possible limit). I've tried computing the terms of this sequence and does seems to approach a limit though (to approx. $1.32$) ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(1%2F2)%5E3%5E(1%2F3)%5E4%5E(1%2F4)%5E5%5E(1%2F5)%5E6%5E(1%2F6)%5E7%5E(1%2F7)%5E8%5E(1%2F8)%5E9%5E(1%2F9)%5E10%5E(1%2F10)%5E11%5E(1%2F11)%5E12%5E(1%2F12)%5E13%5E(1%2F13)%5E14%5E(1%2F14)%5E15%5E(1%2F15)%5E16%5E(1%2F16))).

What might be the possible approach to show the convergence? Is it possible that the sequence might be oscillating (even though with a diminishing amplitude)?

Comment: Might be useful that $n^{1/n} = 1+\ln n/n + O(\ln^2 n/n^2)$.

Comment: You probably want to consider$$f(t)=x^{x^{-t}}\\f(t^\star)=t^\star$$and determine if$$|f'(t^\star)|<1$$

Comment: By implicitly differentiating $y=x^{x^{-y}}$ and setting $dy/dx=0$, I get that $$y\ln(x)=1$$and the maximum occurs at $(2.1318,1.3211)$